# Edit all files in subdirectories with python

Tags: python

I am trying to recursively loop through a series of directories (about 3 levels deep). In each directory is a series of text files, I want to replace a line of text with the directory path if the line contains a certain string so for example.

```
/path/to/text/file/fName.txt
```

If a line in fName in fName.txt text contains the string 'String1' I want to replace this line with 'some text' + file where file is the last part of the path.

This seems like it should be easy in python but I can't seem to manage it.

Edit: Apologies for a very badly written question, I had to rush off, shouldn't have hit enter.

Here's what I have so far

```
import os

for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk("~/dir1/dir2"):
    print files
    for fName in files:
            fpath = os.path.join(dirname, fName)
            print fpath
            f = open(fpath)
            for line in f:
                #where I'm getting stuck
                s = s.replace("old_txt", "new_txt")

            #create new file and save output
```

What I'm getting stuck on is how to replace an entire line based on only a section of the line. For example if the line were

```
That was a useless question,
```

I can't seem to make replace to what I want. What I'm trying to do is change the entire line based only on searching for 'useless'. Also, is there a better way of modyfying a single line than re-writing the entire file?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? i.e. post some code... See [pleac](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/directories.html) for file inspiration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) (look at example) is all you need

parse each file with `with open(...) as f:`, analyze it, and overwrite it (carefully, after testing) with `with open(..., 'w') as f:`